# I can't figure out how to make an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I want that when the "Send to DB" button is clicked, the data from the form is sent to the database and output in the form. A new row of an existing table.

I have a table,under which is a button, which in turn calls a form to send data to the database(At least that's what it's meant to be)

```
<!--Actually the button calling the form and the table-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mine_contract</title>
    <link href="new.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="mine_info">
        <tr>
            <th>№</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Full name of the director</th>
            <th>Phone number</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
            <td><p>1</p></td>
            <td><p>Example name</p></td>
            <td><p>Example address</p></td>
            <td><p>Full name director</p></td>
            <td><p>+00000000000</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__container">
            <div class="popup__wrapper">
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <form action="(I don't understand if there should be something here)" method="POST" class="form">
                    <button class="exit" class="exit" id="closeButton" onclick="delRow()">х</button>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="id">№:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="id" name="id" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="N_m">Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="N_m" name="n_m" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name_m"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Adr">Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Adr" name="Adr_m" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Full_name">Full name of the director:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Full_name" name="director" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Phone">Phone number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone_number" placeholder="Например +00000000000" required>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" name = "submit" id="contact">Send to DB</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>       
    <button id="button" class="button" onclick="addRow()">Open the form</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I call the form using a script

```
//script.js
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
const closeButton = document.querySelector('#closeButton');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.add('open');
  popup.classList.add('popup_open');
});

closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.remove('open');
  popup.classList.remove('popup_open');
});
```

I also wrote a back end (if you can call it that) on Node.js .

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: '',
  host: '',
  database: '',
  password: '',
  port: 5432,
})

const getMineinfo = (request, response) => {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM mine_info', (error, results) => {
       if (error) {
         throw error
    }
    response.status(200).json(results.rows)
     })
}

const createRow = (request, response) => {
    const { n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number } = request.body
  
    pool.query('INSERT INTO mine_info (n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [n_mine, name_mine, adress, full_name_of_direcor, phone_number], (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error
      }
      response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.rows[0].id}`)
    })
  }

module.exports = {
    getMineinfo,
    createRow,
}//Variables from another file
```

```
//another file in which, there are these variables
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('./queries')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(
 bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
)

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.get('/mine_info', db.getMineinfo)
app.post('/mine_info', db.createRow)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`
)})//it works I get the data in the form of JSON by reference http://my-data:3000/mine_info/
```

As I understood and tried to figure out, for what I want, I need to make an AJAX request.
But I don't understand how to do it (maybe I'm stupid), but I ask you to understand this is my first attempt to make such a web application.

I was trying to figure out the AJAX documentation. I tried to solve my problem through fetch, but there I ran into the problem of how to overcome CORS. I also tried to solve my problem through XMLHttpRequest, but I didn't figure it out and it seemed to me an outdated solution (maybe it's not). I ask you to help me, maybe not everything is as difficult as it seems to me, and I express my great gratitude to those who have read this long question.

Comment: fetch and XMLHttpRequest are the only AJAX tools at your disposal (not that your code uses either) ... the CORS issue can be fixed on your server side using `cors` module

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yes, I understand that fetch and XMLHttpRequest are the only tools to solve this problem, unfortunately I don't know how to use them. As for the CORS module on the server side, thanks for the hint, most likely, prescribing header ```headers("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8")``` will help me avoid problems with CORS. But I have serious problems with AJAX, I don't even understand where the request should be located (

Comment: Oh, you said you tried to use fetch and XMLHttpRequest - sorry, misunderstood what you said

Comment: @JaromandaX, don't apologize, I understand that my question turned out to be a long one and it was possible not to replace it. And in my lack of understanding, only I am to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the data from the input fields, and make a POST request to this route and pass that data:

```
app.post('/mine_info'
```

So, you need to:

1. add submit event listener to the form

you don't need form attributes, as you're making a request manually with JavaScript, but add a CSS identifier to get the form element)

```
<form id="myForm" class="form">
```

get the form:

```
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');
```

add submit event listener:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {

e.preventDefault();
```

2. collect form input fields, and serialize request payload

now you need to get the value of every input field.

you could select each element with DOM selector, but there is a one-liner that does that for you automatically, with Form data (see this guide for further info and if you need to send a file as well: [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects):

pass form element to Form data constructor

```
new FormData(form)
```

now, you'll make a JSON request, so turn all entries to JSON object, which will be posted.
And on the server, `bodyParser` will process that JSON request (if you want to add a file, then you'd post multipart requst, and you'd need multipart processing middleware, such as multer)

```
const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
```

3. post fields to the route

use native `fetch` to make a JSON requst, so add JSON as a content type, and encode JSON object to `body` parameter (see this guide for further info: [Using the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch))

```
try {
    const response = await fetch('/mine_info', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

    // parse response: .text() is for text format, use .json() for JSON response
    const result = await response.text();

    console.log('result', result)

    // show the message in the DOM
    // ..

} catch (error) {
    // show some error message in the DOM
    console.log('err: ', error);
}
```

(note: your server sends response with `res.send`, which means it's a textual format, so you need to use `.text()`, but should you use `res.json` instead, then you'd need to use `.json()` to parse the response)

full code:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('myForm');

form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    const data = Object.fromEntries(new FormData(form).entries());
    
    console.log('data to post: ', data);

    try {
        const response = await fetch('/mine_info', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });

        const result = await response.text();
        console.log('result', result)

        // show the message in the DOM
        // ..
   
    } catch (error) {
        
        // show some error message in the DOM
        console.log('err: ', error);
    }

});
```

```html
 <form id="myForm">
                    <button class="exit" class="exit" id="closeButton" onclick="delRow()">х</button>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="id">№:</label>
                        <input type="number" id="id" name="id" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="N_m">Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="N_m" name="n_m" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name_m"  required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Adr">Address:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Adr" name="Adr_m" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Full_name">Full name of the director:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Full_name" name="director" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="string">
                        <label for="Phone">Phone number:</label>
                        <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone_number" placeholder="Например +00000000000" required>
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit" name = "submit" id="contact">Send to DB</button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: That explained a lot to me, you're a cool person. Only I'm not here, and I didn't understand where to write this script in the front end or in the back (how shameful ()

Comment: in the front-end, add it in `script.js` file. use `console.log` with each element and part of the code to help you understand it better

Comment: You're the best person, you explained to me a bunch of information I read that I couldn't structure in my head.

Comment: well, I sort of figured out the recording and it seems to work (I need a couple more edits). And in order to output as a new line, you need to make a similar request only GET, I understood correctly.

Comment: yes: change fetch parameters: `method: 'GET'`, and remove `body` (body is sent only with POST requests) and since you have `res.json` on the server, you need to parse response with `response.json()`, and then you can for example draw table rows with for loop iterating that response data, but that's another question

Comment: Really the best, I'll try to implement GET myself first. Yes, I understand that it's a different question, but I'll try it myself from the beginning. Sorry I didn't immediately mark your answer as a "Solution".